# Probability for Joint CDF of two Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a joint CDF of two random Variables $F(x,y)$. I need to determine the probability that $Y$ is greater than some value $y_1$ given that $X$ is equal to some value $x_1$?

Also I want to  determine  the  probability  that $Y$ is  greater  than  some value $y_1$ given that $X$ is greater than some value $x_1$?

For the First Part differentiating the Joint CDF would yield me a Joint PDF $f(x,y)=\frac{d^2 F(x,y)}{dx\ dy}$. Also from Conditional Probability theorem I can deduce the Value of $Y$ at $x_1$ as $f(y|x1)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$. Using this Probability equation would be as

$P(Y > y_1 | x = x_1) = \int_{y_1}^\infty f(y|x1)\ dy$

And for the Second Part I cannot use the Conditional Probability since it is given $X$ is greater than some value $x_1$
Then the Probabilty equation would turn out as

$\begin{eqnarray} P(Y > y_1 | X > x_1) & = & \frac{P(Y > y_1 \cap X > x_1)}{P(X > x_1)} \\
& = & \frac{\int_{y_1}^\infty \int_{x_1}^\infty f(x,y)\ dxdy}{\int_{x_1}^\infty f(x) dx} \end{eqnarray}$

Are the Answers to above questions Correct? I have understood the Concept but I am bit Skeptical with my Results. Any reply confirming the same would be much appreciated

Comment: I've taken a shot at writing your equations using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) so that they display properly. If you go to edit the text you can see what I've done, and fix anything that isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

The answers seem correct, but I see that you are twice differentiating then integrating *back* in the first problem -- two steps down and one step back up.   You can save some work by just stepping down once.

Since $$\int_{-\infty}^{y_1} \left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^2 F(s,t)}{\mathrm d s~\mathrm d t}\right\rvert_{s:=x_1}~\mathrm d t ~=~ \left.\dfrac{\mathrm d F(s, y_1)}{\mathrm d s}\right\rvert_{s:=x_1}$$

Then we have:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y>y_1\mid X=x_1) ~&=~1-\left.\dfrac{~~\dfrac{\mathrm d F(s,y_1)}{\mathrm d s}~~}{\dfrac{\mathrm d F(s,\infty)}{\mathrm d s}}\right\vert_{s:=x_1}\end{align}$$

---

The second problem can be solved without using *any* calculus.   You were taking two steps down and two steps back up!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So in the first Problem , to get the Exceeding Probability do we need to get the CCDF(1-CDF). Also apologies but could you please elaborate on what you meant for the second Problem.

Comment: For the first: It's just $\mathsf P(Y>y_1\mid X=x_1)=1-\mathsf P(Y\leq y_1\mid X=x_1)$, with the later evaluated the definition of conditioning but with the numerator and denominator using density of $X$.   For the second: recall that $\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)=1-\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Ok understood and thanks for the Explanation, However I just have a slight doubt, Can't we express the First and Second Case in terms of Integrals using Probability Theory?. Because I would end up with same answer as what you have wrote right?. Also for the Second Case .

Comment: Sure, @suzdeex8197 . You *can* express them as integrals of the joint pdf. However, you did not *start* with that.  So it would be preferable to express things in terms of *what you already knew*: the joint CDF.   As I said, t saves work. There is no need to take two steps down and two steps up, when you can just use what was given as it is.

Comment: sounds accurate understood it. However could you be please specify what you meant for the second Part using the Complement . I understood your concept but I am not able to visualize how can that be expressed as Joint CDF. Apologies I am new to this so Lot of questions.